# catch error results from scalaz Task

Tags: scala, scalaz

I am new to scala and coming from an all python background. I currently have the following code to save an annotation to a cassandra db, Item is a model I have n a separate file:

```
trait DoTask {
  def annotate(item: String, annotation: String): Task[Item]
}

object DoTask {
  def apply(log: Log)(implicit pool: ExecutorService): DoTask =
    new DoTask with Logging {
      def annotate(item: String, annotation: String): Task[Item] = {
        val item = Item(item, annotation)

        (log write item) >>
        (logger infoT s"item: $item") >>
        (Task now item)
      }
}
```

The task runs and I am able to perform the annotation successfully, but I am having problems grasping the error catching mechanism. In python I could do a try-except or result.get("error") if I had a dict as a response. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Scala also has a try / catch construct.

Comment: Where is `Log` defined? Please provide a minimal example that includes all necessary code to run it. Check out this Twitter thread on `Task#now` and `Task#delay` - https://twitter.com/Gentmen/status/837652706848276482.